# Recursive method that reverses numbers?

Tags: recursion, numbers, integer, reverse, digits

> ```
> public void printReverseDigits( int input )
> ```
>
> Prints the digits in the input integer, in reverse order.  You may
>   assume the input will always be greater than 0.  For example:
>
> ```
> > RecursionFun f = new RecursionFun()
> > f.printReverseDigits( 12345 )
> 54321
> > f.printReverseDigits( 20 )
> 02
> > f.printReverseDigits( 404 )
> 404
> > f.printReverseDigits( 1 )
> 1
> ```

I don't even know where to start on this ^. We can't use loops or anything of that sort... only recursion, if statements, stuff like that. 
Any ideas on how to even begin? :( I don't get it...

Comment: you should start by looking at the modulus and div operations ( % and / )

Comment: You should leave your question as others may find it useful, I dont know why you've deleted the question and changed the title ??

Comment: Please don't deface your question after you've received an answer. The point of Stack Overflow is to create a resource of use to many people in the future, not just those asking questions. You've gotten good answers here, so I don't want to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy if the number of digits is known, if not you could check it by seeing if the number if the number is less than 9, then 99 then 999, and so on.
If the number is 404, `if(input<999)` will return true, then we know it is of three digits.

```
...in a loop for number of digits....
digit[i] = input % 10;
input = input / 10;
```

Then you could combine the digits in reverse and return it.

For recursion:

```
int printReverseDigits(int input)
    {          
        int digit, new;
        if(!input) return 0;
        digit=input%10;
        new=printReverseDigits(input/10);
        cout<<digit; 
        return new+digit; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print out the units - **number % 10**,

then remove the units - **number / 10**,

and carry on if the number is **non 0** using recursion instead of a loop

```
f.printReverseDigits( int num )
{
  print( "%d", num % 10 );
  num /= 10;
  if( num )
  {
    printReverseDigits( num );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple really.  Here is a c++ solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void recursivePrintVals(const int someNum) {
    if(!someNum) return;
    cout << someNum % 10;
    recursivePrintVals(someNum/10);
}

int main() {
    recursivePrintVals(123456789);
}
```